# Sobrecarga del servidor de aplicaciones web

Tags: java, gvnix, maven, spring-roo

Saludos.
He creado una aplicación web para gestionar una clínica veterinaria con las herramientas **Spring Roo** y **Gvnix** , he creado la base de datos con las tablas veterinarios , dueños , mascotas , citas , todas estas tablas se relacionan de 1 a muchos entre ellas , excepto la tabla tratamientos y medicamentos que se relacionan de muchos a muchos , entre estas 2 tablas anteriormente mencionadas hay una tabla intermedia llamada tratamiento_med la cual sirve para relacionarse entre ellas , como gestor de base de datos uso **MySQL workbench** y como servidor **MYSQL Server** todo me funciona bien , desde los formularios de la aplicación web puedo *crear* , *actualizar* y *borrar* dueños , mascotas , veterinarios , citas , medicamentos , pero cuando intento crear más de 2 registros sobre la tabla tratamientos haciendo una selección múltiple en los medicamentos que tiene relacionado con la tabla tratamientos mediante una etiqueta jspx

```
<field:select field="Med"  id="c_com_clinicaveterinaria_dam_domain_Tratamiento_Med" itemValue="id" items="${medicamentoses}" multiple="true" path="/medicamentoses" z="+hr+pOBWxfr2whYp+joa+OMxAHk="/>
```

La aplicación me da un error sin detalle de porque y se me cae por completo.

- Me fijo en los procesos y veo que a la hora de crear nuevos registros en la tabla intermedia **tratamiento_med** , el proceso del **Administrador de tareas de Windows** con el nombre **Java(TM) Plataform SE Binary** ( java.exe ) se dispara a más de **+1.800KB**  ( espacio de trabajo privado ) , lo cual hace que se caía la aplicación web.

Se que el problema radica en esta parte de código de la clase AspectJ de persistencia del Gvnix con el nombre

```
privileged aspect TratamientoBatchService_Roo_GvNIXJpaBatch {
```

Exactamente en esta parte de código :

```
@Transactional
public void TratamientoBatchService.create(List<Tratamiento> tratamientoes) {
    for( Tratamiento tratamiento : tratamientoes) {
        tratamiento.persist();
    }
}
```

El error que me muestra por consola del IDE IntelliJ es este :

```
Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:421)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:272)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle.appendFieldSeparator(ToStringStyle.java:1503)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle.appendFieldEnd(ToStringStyle.java:1526)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle.append(ToStringStyle.java:439)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder.append(ToStringBuilder.java:848)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.appendFieldsIn(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:522)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:683)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:282) at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:145) at com.clinicaveterinaria.dam.domain.Citas_Roo_ToString.ajc$interMethod$com_clinicaveterinaria_dam_domain_Citas_Roo_ToString$com_clinicaveterinaria_dam_domain_Citas$toString(Citas_Roo_ToString.aj:13)
at com.clinicaveterinaria.dam.domain.Citas.toString(Citas.java:1)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:265)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle.appendDetail(ToStringStyle.java:586)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle.appendInternal(ToStringStyle.java:550)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle.append(ToStringStyle.java:436)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder.append(ToStringBuilder.java:848)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.appendFieldsIn(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:522)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:683)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:282)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:145)
at com.clinicaveterinaria.dam.domain.Tratamiento_Roo_ToString.ajc$interMethod$com_clinicaveterinaria_dam_domain_Tratamiento_Roo_ToString$com_clinicaveterinaria_dam_domain_Tratamiento$toString(Tratamiento_Roo_ToString.aj:13)
at com.clinicaveterinaria.dam.domain.Tratamiento.toString(Tratamiento.java:1)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:317)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
```

He probado a configurar el servidor **Maven** desde el IDE IntelliJ IDEA para aumentar la cantidad de memoria que puede soportar mediante **"-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"** , he instalado el JDK 6 , 7 , 8 y muchas cosas más , nada funciona , necesito saberlo porque es para el proyecto de fin de grado.

*No estoy seguro pero creo que la solución sería crear una especie de **BufferBuilder** que vaya cargando poco a poco los objetos en la maquina virtual de java , pero no tengo ni idea de como hacer eso o algo parecido.*

Gracias por vuestra atención.

Comment: agrega tu codigo  donde usas BufferedReader o donde realizas copia de array?

Comment: El problema está en los métodos `toString`. Intenta comentarlos y ejecutar tu aplicación nuevamente. Recomendación: no utilices Spring Roo ni generadores de código si no sabes el tipo de código que generan por ti ni mucho menos sabes cómo es que ese código funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Saludos.
La solución es la que me dio Luiggi Mendoza.
Tenía que sobrescribir el metodo toString de la clase

```
package com.clinicaveterinaria.dam.domain;

import com.clinicaveterinaria.dam.domain.Tratamiento;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle;

privileged aspect Tratamiento_Roo_ToString {
public String Tratamiento.toString() {
    return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);
   }    
}
```

Y definir el método de esta forma.

```
package com.clinicaveterinaria.dam.domain;

import com.clinicaveterinaria.dam.domain.Tratamiento;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle;

privileged aspect Tratamiento_Roo_ToString {

public String Tratamiento.toString() {
    return "";
      }
   }
```

Muchas gracias por la solución.
Puedo seguir con el proyecto.

Comment: La solución **no** es la correcta: la siguiente vez que arranques la consola de Roo este fichero se volverá a modificar. La forma de hacer esto en Spring Roo es definiendo el método **dentro del fichero `.java`**, así, Roo detecta que ya se ha definido el método y no lo vuelve a generar. En la cabecera de los ficheros _.aj_ `// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. THIS FILE IS MANAGED BY SPRING ROO. // You may push code into the target .java compilation unit if you wish to edit any member(s).`

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario , ahora mismo lo arreglo como me has comentado , no me di cuenta de ese detalle.

Answer (score 0):

**Modificando las variables para incrementar el heap size de tu IDE no implicaría ningún cambio.**

Revisando tu error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at
>   java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)

En algún lugar estás usando un `bufferedReader.readLine()` leyendo algún archivo vacío.

Otro problema común es crear multiples arreglos, he visto comúnmente que en un loop realizan copia de o creación de arrays.

En realidad el problema es que estas alojando mas memoria de la permitida, por esa razón el `OutOfMemoryError`.